# How can I make this database schema better?

Tags: php, mysql, database, moodle

I currently have two tables in which stores the attendances of a student in a course. I have the hub_attendance table which stores the total attendances of a student and the hub_attendance_lesson where it stores the attendance of each lesson that a student has or has not attended. I'm not sure if this is correct or if I'm doing anything wrong, I'm a beginner in databases!

```
hub_attendance:
id
student_id
course_id
total_lessons
total_lessons_so_far
total_attended
total_absent
total_excused_absent
total_late
total_excused_late

hub_attendance_lesson:
id
lesson_id
course_id
student_id
date
attended
absent
excused_absent
late
excused_late
```

EDIT:

So I've gotten rid of the first table completely and this is my new single table.

```
Hub_Attendance:
id
lesson_id
course_id
student_id
date
attendance
```

Comment: How are you defining an attendance? Per lesson or per group of lessons? Some details of the real-world situation you are facing would make the design issues clearer.

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure what you mean by group of lessons?

Comment: As in does a single attendance contain multiple lessons? Database design is about working out what the unique data records are and the relationships between them. If you have a single student course enrolment, which will then have many attendances at various component lessons, this is different from having no overarching enrolment and just having lots of attendances that you need to count. The difference is whether you need to store data about the enrolment which will otherwise be repeated in the attendances table e.g. enrolment start date.

Comment: I have students, courses and lessons. A student can be in many courses and lessons. Each course contains 10 lessons maximum but at least 6. What I am trying to build right now is an attendance module for a part of a website where it stores the attendance of a student in a course. For attendance they can be attended, absent, late, excused late or absent. 

A student is able to click on the attendance link and depending on the course they are currently viewing it should show all the attendances of all the 6-10 lessons within that course. It would show past, present and future lessons.

Comment: I've suggested a schema as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Dutchie432 said, you don't need the first table because it introduces unnecessary redundancy and you can count those statistics on the fly. Such aggregate tables can be a good solution if performance is an issue, but they should be used only as a last resort.

About the second table - you have separate fields `attended`, `absent`, `excused_absent`, 
`late` and `excused_late`. Aren't these mutually exclusive? So only one of them can be true for one row? If so, you may be better off with one enumeration field called for example `attendance`, which would take different values for each of those states. In that way you could't have rows where none of the flags, or more than one flag, is set.

Comment: Hey, thanks! So should attendance be a varchar or ENUM? What would be better or does it not matter?

Comment: ENUM would be better than VARCHAR because it would guard you against inserting a value not belonging to specified correct values. If your database is very big, you could also consider storing the attendance as a TINYINT, with constants for different states - for example, ABSENT = 0, ATTENDED = 1, etc. It would probably be a little faster that way, if somewhat less readable.

Comment: Thank you :) My new table is very very small now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need:

```
**Course**
id, name, etc...

**Lesson**
id, courseid, name, etc...

**Attendance**
id, studentid, lessonid, lateness, etc...

**Enrolment**
id, courseid, studentid, startdate, etc...
```

You need the enrolment table to know that students should be on a course even if they never turn up for lessons. The attendance table will allow you to have many students per lesson and many lessons per student. This is a [many-to-many table](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Understanding_SQL_Many_to_Many_Relationships.aspx). Any aggregation and counting can be done in SQL.

Comment: Cheers. Sorry I don't explain things very well. But I'm using Moodle right now (it's a learning management system) and it already has the course and lesson table and that's where I fetch those data from so that part is sorted for me already. It also has a role assignments table where I can check if they are students for that course so my main table I'm trying to create into the Moodle system is the attendance.

Comment: Thought you might be :) There's an attendance module or two that already exists that you may wish to check out as a starting point. Check the plugins directory : http://moodle.org/plugins/search.php?s=attendance

Comment: Oh oh, do you use Moodle? 

Our system is using version 1.9 and we're just building a simple one from scratch just so it tailors our needs :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on an enrolment plugin for it right now. Try the old plugins database - there are a couple more for 1.9 you can check out: http://moodle.org/mod/data/view.php?d=13&perpage=10&search=attendance&sort=0&order=DESC&advanced=0&filter=1&f_44=&f_45=&f_46=&f_47=&f_48=&f_49=&f_51=&f_96=&f_97=&f_98=&f_99=&f_100=&f_101=&f_195=&f_213=&f_214=&f_215=&f_216=&u_fn=&u_ln=

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your schema correctly, Your first table can be totally eliminated. You should be able to fetch the totals using MySQL.

```
select count(id) as total_late from hub_attendance_lesson where late=true and student_id=TheUserId
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this first table, every total can be fetch using SQL :

```
SELECT count(id) AS absent
FROM hub_attendance_lesson 
WHERE lesson_id = <your lesson id>
AND absent = <false / true>
```

I guess you'll be able to adapt this code for your needs.